# How to turn navigationBar back to nontransparent?

Tags: ios, swift

How do I change the `navigationBar` back to nontransparent in one view after I have made it transparent with this piece of code in `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried:

```
self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
self.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil  
// or
self.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
```

and of course:

```
self.navigationBar.translucent = **false**
```

Comment: Setting backgroundImage and shadowImage to nil did the trick, thanks alot!